# View is rendered even the request is unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I have an MVC app where I have an Admin area. When user is not logged in I'm redirecting the request to login page with custom AuthorizeAttribute.

```
public class UserAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var user = AdminGlobals.CurrentUser;

        if (user == null || !user.IsActive)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = AdminGlobals.CurrentUser;
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        //Do not redirect if the request is already redirecting
        if (context.Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected) return;

        if (user == null || !user.IsActive)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/login", true);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/unauthorized", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller and action:

```
[UserAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

And in the view I have:

```
Hello @AdminGlobals.CurrentUser.Title
```

When the application is in debug mode I'm having NullReferenceExceptions for inside the view and also the layout page since it tries to use same variable @AdminGlobals.CurrentUser which is null. I know I can easily prevent this but I cannot understand why the view is rendered when the request is not authorized. Is it possible to use RedirectToAction inside AuthorizeAttribute to prevent rendering of the view?

Comment: I'm assuming you left something out, since your AuthorizeCore override shouldn't compile - you don't have a return value for the "else" condition.

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes, updated that section.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you're not using Identity in some fashion? Claims-based authentication is somewhat simple to implement, and you could combine that with an extension to Principal to get your Title value. That would let you use the baked-in authorization bits (like Request.IsAuthenticated).

Comment: This is actually my first asp.net MVC project and I'm trying to use Dapper + Unity. I did lot of webforms projects where I had custom auth code and now I'm trying to move to MVC. I would like to use latest trends of course :). I was planning to check "PRO .NET Design Pattern Framework 4.5" in which OAuth is used but didn't have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that using Response in a filter is the way to go. Typically, you leverage the filterContext to perform your redirect. For example:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var user = AdminGlobals.CurrentUser;
    var context = filterContext.HttpContext;

    //Do not redirect if the request is already redirecting
    if (context.Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected) return;

    var routeData = new RouteValueDictionary(new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Unauthorized"
    });

    if (user == null || !user.IsActive)
    {
        routeData = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" });
    }

    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Default", routeData);
}
```

I'm assuming from your code that both actions are on the HomeController; otherwise, update the controller name to the correct value.

"Default," in the constructor for the RedirectToRouteResult object, is the name of the route in your RouteConfig that you want to be applied.

Also, use the HttpContext from the filerContext.

Comment: Is it possible to add a query string returnUrl in RouteValueDictionary? Otherwise I guess I need to use RedirectResult($"/login?returnUrl={returnUrl}")

Comment: I would assume yes - it would just be another entry in the route dictionary. Something like `routeData = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", returnUrl = "whatever" });`